# RHEL + how to capture fresh kernel message without machine reboot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, redhat-enterprise-linux, kernel, dmesg

here is example from `dmesg` output from important production server ( RHEL 7.2 - DELL machine HW )
as we can see the `sde` disk in server is dying

```
[Wed Jun 30 11:24:58 2021] sd 0:2:4:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Jun 30 11:26:18 2021] sd 0:2:4:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Jun 30 11:26:18 2021] sd 0:2:4:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Jun 30 11:27:28 2021] sd 0:2:4:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[Wed Jun 30 11:27:46 2021] sd 0:2:4:0: [sde] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
```

what is interesting is that these messages are old from `2021` , and we not seen this messages on `2022/2023`

based on that facts, I want to ask if disk replacement should be considered based on faulty disk messages from `2021`

second important question, is how to capture new fresh kernel messages by `dmesg`

is it possible to re-create new fresh kernel messages ?

as I know maybe reboot machine can helps about this , but I want to avoid machine reboot